# Saving Advanced Searches for later use

Tags: search

Can advanced searches be saved for later use and made to appear in the Search menu, so users dont need to enter the search criteria every time? Similar to how custom reports can be created once and added as a menu item under Search?

regards
Sudesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the result of an advanced Search as a Smart Group. If you want a link to that smart group in the menu, you can add a menu option for it with **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Navigation Menu**. 
[image: Customize CiviCRM navigation]

Comment: Ok, I see. Can you then add this smart group somehow as a menu option under Search?

Comment: You can add menu options with Administer/Customize Data and Screens/Navigation Menu. You can add any internal or external URL to the menu. So you save the URL of the Smart Group and add it to the menu?

Comment: Or to keep things simple, just search for the group in simple search.

Comment: But this solutions only works for Contact Searches, not for Participant or Member searches