# Can you save an advanced activity search?

Tags: civireport, activities, custom-search

After using Advanced Search to create a pretty detailed search on activities, I need to save it.  If my search results were contacts, I could create a smart group based on the search which would essentially make the search permanently available as suggested here: [Saving Advanced Searches for later use](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/599/saving-advanced-searches-for-later-use)

However, my search is **on activities and displays activities**.  I need to perform this search frequently and there is no corresponding tool like smart groups for activities.

I also need to be able to use the **Batch Update Activities by Profile** action on the search results which precludes me from simply creating a report and saving that.

Comment: If you save it as a (contact) Smart Group then is the problem that it means you have to click 'edit SG criteria' each time and reset the search to 'display as Activities' to get what you need?

Answer (score 2):

The key functionality to do this was added in CiviCRM 4.7.25, with [CRM-20630](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/projects/CRM/issues/CRM-20630).

My understanding is that it's *almost* but not quite what you need.  This allows you to pass variables through in the Activity Search URL, but it won't generate the URL for you - you'll have to figure the URL out for your search.  A extension to auto-generate the URL seems like a worthy project though.

The feature doesn't seem to be documented yet, but you can see examples [on Github](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10957).

Answer (score 1):

Look under contacts -> 'custom search' for something that matches. If that doesn't get you something then it may be time to ask a partner to build you something bespoke, or upgrade CiviCRM for you.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a smart group (with its gid), you create an associated saved-search (with an ssid).

Both have their own URL, that you can use to display their result :

https://yoursite/civicrm/group/search?force=1&context=smog&gid=30
or
https://yoursite/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?force=1&reset=1&ssID=10&context=advanced

But they don't provide the same result : particularly, with the saved search, you can use a custom Profile to display your list, while the smart group will only display a "default view" (as far as I can see it).

You can find the link gid<>ssid in the civicrm_group table (I don't know if and where you can find it in the UI, nor find a saved-search ssid)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to save it as a (contact) Smart Group. Then you would need to click 'edit Smart Group criteria' and reset the search to 'display as Activities' to get what you need I think